# Raygun Rich User Tracking?

Tags: javascript, raygun, raygun.io

Raygun boasts of Rich User Tracking. However they ask us to provide the following data:

```
// V2
rg4js('setUser', {
  identifier: 'user_email_address@localhost.local',
  isAnonymous: false,
  email: 'emailaddress@localhost.local',
  firstName: 'Foo',
  fullName: 'Foo Bar',
  uuid: 'BAE62917-ACE8-ab3D-9287-B6A33B8E8C55'
});

// V1
Raygun.setUser('user_email_address@localhost.local', 
  false,
  'user_email_address@localhost.local', 
  'Foo', 
  'Foo Bar', 
  'BAE62917-ACE8-ab3D-9287-B6A33B8E8C55');
```

How is this rich user tracking if we are expected to provide the user data?
Is my undestanding wrong?

What if we have a number of users using the application, what then?
Is there anybody who has tried out this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raygun does not know who your users are. Instead, they have to ask you to provide the user details when an error is reported.

Adding user details allows you to use Raygun see which users have encountered a particular error. It also allows you to look at a user and see which errors a specific user has encountered.

You can use an identifier from your system instead of sending a users personal information.

However, most people miss the point the when a user encounters an error, you have a great customer service opportunity. I had a user who found an error and I emailed them to apologize and tell them that bug has been logged and will be fixed. That user thought they had done something wrong and was so impressed with the pro-active customer service that they became a loyal customer.

Comment: it does sound like a useful customer service provision, its just that if you have more than 100 people accessing your site, then I don't know how feasible this is. But thank you for your clarification , I'll go ahead and mark it accepted.

Comment: it works very well. It is always good to have the information to look back on, especially if you can identify your important customers, or those who experience a lot of errors. Convert them and you have free advertising from them for life.